# Paring text converted from PDF

Tags: python, string, parsing, pdf, text

I have some troubles of parsing strings converted from a PDF file, which was fulfilled by `pdftotext.exe` with option `-table`. As it is listed below, the converted text contains some empty lines, but it can be trimmed easily. However, sometimes, it break one line into multiple pieces. For instance, "Benzenesulfonic acid mono-C10-16-alkyl derivs., sodium salts" is treated three lines. Is there a way to fix or overcome this issue like scan the text file by column? Thanks in advance.

#### pseudo code

```
with open(fname) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

#remove empty lines
Chemicals_new=[line for line in content if line.strip()]
Chemicals_new[0].split("  ") ###need some help here...
```

#### Sample of converted text file

```
          Chemical Name                    Synonyms                 Trade Secret               CAS-No       Weight %

          Sodium carbonate                        -                      No                    497-19-8                     25 - 30

Silicic acid, aluminum sodium salt                -                      No                    1344-00-9                    15 - 20

         Benzenesulfonic acid,                    -                      No                    68081-81-2                   10 - 15

mono-C10-16-alkyl derivs., sodium

              salts
```

Comment: Probably not in a generic way, a way that can be easily used in other use cases. Without seeing more of that converted pdf, I would suggest as a first trial to split by tabs (if there are any used to delimit the columns) or split by the amount of characters wide each column is, followed by a check if "synonyms" or "trade secrets" is empty. If so, append the first field of that line to the first field of the previous.

Comment: @OliverW.- Thanks for your suggestion. At this moment, I am using your approach, and parse those strings by fixed width. Wait and see any other ideas come.